# Deep linking with <select>, angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to enable deep linking with the select element

```
<select ng-model="query">
    <option ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.code}}</option>
</select>
```

So when I choose something, I want the url to change to app/productcode

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your select to:

```
<select ng-model="query" ng-options="product.code for product in products"></select>
```

In your controller, you'll use the $location service to change to the route you want via a watch. Something along the lines of:

```
$scope.$watch('query', function() {
   $location.path('/some/route/' + query);
});
```